# Cleaner code to get around Printing an Int value in Python

Tags: python, printing, int

I have a piece of code that asks for a users age. The user's input is of type `int`. In addition, if the user doesn't want to enter anything they can just press 'Enter' to exit the program (below):

```
print("What is your age?")
answer = int(input())
if answer == '':
    print("Don't want to disclose? That's fine.")
```

However, when I just press Enter I get a error below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/test/PycharmProjects/exceptions/testinput.py", line 2, in <module>
    answer = int(input())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I know I can do a try block and the code works like I want to below:

```
print("What is your age?")
try:
    answer = int(input())
    if answer == '':
        print()
except ValueError:
        print("Don't want to disclose? That's fine.")
```

My question is, is there a way, other than a `try` block, to print a blank value of type `int`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other way is to *look before you leap*, use `if-else` and do the `int` conversion when needed inside `else`:

```
answer = input("What is your age?")

if answer == "":
    print("Don't want to disclose? That's fine.")
else:
    answer = int(answer)
```

But now you need consider if `answer` is valid integer constituting string or not e.g. what if the user inputs `foobar`? (**Hint:** now you also need that check with `str.isdecimal` or alike methods).

Answer (score 3):

Of course: check the input *before* you convert to int:

```
answer = input("What is your age? ")
if answer == '':
    print("Don't want to disclose? That's fine.")
else:
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

I would remove the `input` call from within the `int` function.

```py
print("What is your age?")
answer = input()
answer = int(answer) if answer else None
if not answer: print("Don't want to disclose? That's fine.")
```

Comment: The logic is redundant, in that you've checked `answer` twice.

Comment: You are right @Prune . Bad logic there with the print statement beforehand too.

Answer (score 0):

The input function converts the input in to `String` as mentioned in the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input)

> input([prompt]) If the prompt argument is present, it is written to
>   standard output without a trailing newline. The function then reads a
>   line from input, converts it to a string (stripping a trailing
>   newline), and returns that. When EOF is read, EOFError is raised.

So, when you are entering nothing, you are trying to int type convert a string(`''`), similar to `int('xyz')`, therefore getting a value error exception

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'xyz'

If a number enclosed in `String` type, e.g. `int('2')`, its type converted well.

You can perhaps do it this way instead:

```
print("What is your age?")
answer = input()
if answer == '':
    print("Don't want to disclose? That's fine.")
else:
    int(answer)
```